# Form Fields return null after applying AJAX

Tags: html, ajax, forms, jsp, validation

I recently applied form validation using AJAX to my user registration form. Previously, I had validated the form fields using javascript only and it worked fine. But after applying AJAX, the form fields return 'null' values after submitting the form. Here is my code to the user registration form:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="362" style = "font-size:26px;font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:black"><b>Create an Account</b></td>
  </tr>
  <form action = "create_user.jsp" method = "post" name = "form1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type = "text" class = "border" id = "nm1" placeholder = "Name" onblur="validate('nm',this.value);" />
      <span id="nm"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="email" class = "border" id = "id1" placeholder = "E-mail ID" onblur="validate('id',this.value);" />
      <span id="id"></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="password" class = "border" id = "password1" placeholder = "Password" onblur="validate('password',this.value);" />
      <span id='password'></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="password" class = "border" id = "retype_pass1" placeholder = "Retype Password" onblur="validate('retype_pass',this.value);"  />
      <span id="retype_pass"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td><input type = "submit" id = "button" name = "register" value = "Create an Account" disabled onClick = "return validation()"  /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

Here is the validate() function used:

```
function validate(field, query) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
} else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a href='index.php'>Reload Or Try     Again</a> the page.";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "validate.jsp?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the validate.jsp file:

```
<%!
String pass;
%>
<%
String field = request.getParameter("field");
String query = request.getParameter("query");
if(field.equals("nm"))
{
        if(query.length() == 0)
            out.print("<span style='color:red;'>*Mandatory Field</span>");
}

if(field.equals("password"))
{
    if(query.length() == 0)
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>*Mandatory Field</span>");
    else if(query.length() > 0 && query.length() <= 5)
    {
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>Weak</span>");

    }
    else
        out.print("<html><body><span style='color:green;'>Strong</span></body></html>");
    pass = query;
}
if(field.equals("id"))
{
    if(query.length() == 0)
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>*Mandatory Field</span>");
}
if(field.equals("retype_pass"))
{
    if(!(query.equals(pass)))
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>Password and Retype Mismatch</span>");
    else if(query.length() == 0)
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>*Mandatory Field</span>");
}
if(field.equals("bday"))
{
    if(query.length() == 0)
        out.print("<span style='color:red;'>*Mandatory Field</span>");
}
%>
```

Now after I click the Submit button and check the entries in the database I have created for the user, all the fields show NULL.What may be the problem?

Comment: We need to see the `validate.jsp` content.

Comment: @lolka_bolkaok i'm uploading the validate.jsp file also

Answer (score 0):

It may seems a little weird, but in order your `form` to work correctly, you should consider the following:

- A `form` is [not allowed](http://validator.w3.org/) to be a **child** element of a `table`, `tbody` or `tr`.
- You can have an entire table inside a `form`.
- You can have a `form` inside a `table` cell.
- You cannot have part of a `table` inside a `form`.

So you may use one `form` around the entire `table`. Then either use the clicked submit button to determine which row to process (to be quick) or process every row (allowing bulk updates).

Comment: Is this the case with ajax only? Because it worked fine when I applied javascript.